# How to get complication data of Wear OS on Mobile devices?

Tags: android, wear-os

I've read this page.
https://docs.kustom.rocks/tags/complication-data/

According to this document, it looks like there is a way to get complication data of a watch device on a mobile device.

Is it possible?
If true, how to get data?